# Average of List Attributes in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of objects, with an attribute (`attributions`) that I want to average (element-wise) together. What is the best way of doing it?

I have the objects (`ExplanationObjects`) in a list `attr`, each of which has an attribute `attributions` that I want to average together, in an element-wise fashion. For instance, if I had:

```
a.attribution=[[2,1],[4,6]]
```

and

```
b.attribution=[[4,3],[8,8]]
```

I would want to get

```
[[3,2],[6,7]]
```

Right now, I'm doing that by using

```
(sum(a.attribution for a in attrs))/len(attrs)
```

Is that the best way of doing it, or is there another method (numpy preferred) that you'd suggest?

Comment: What about [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your attribute to a numpy array you can do that. This would look neater if you made attribution an array in your class. I don't know if you can do that, so my example does not.

```
import numpy as np

class C:
    def __init__(self, attribution):
        self.attribution = attribution

a=C([[2,1],[4,6]])
b=C([[4,3],[8,8]])

print(a.attribution)
print(b.attribution)

a_array = np.array(a.attribution)
b_array = np.array(b.attribution)

print((a_array + b_array)/2)
print(np.mean([a_array, b_array], axis=0))
print((a_array + b_array)//2) # preserve int
```

I have done it a few different ways. You can add and divide by 2, or you can use `numpy.mean`.

output

```
[[2, 1], [4, 6]]
[[4, 3], [8, 8]]
[[3. 2.]
 [6. 7.]]
[[3. 2.]
 [6. 7.]]
[[3 2]
 [6 7]]
```